# "Image reflecting" program (not actual image, just reflects drawings made with characters)

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, multidimensional-array

This is the code I have. There are two functions, one that prints the image and one that reverses. I'm not good with pointers and arrays. I understand I have to return the array as a pointer because functions do not return arrays. So I don't know which are the mistakes. I know how to do it without the use of functions, but I must do it with separate functions. When I print the image(yes it's a pikachu) I save it from the file and print it to see if it saves correctly and yes it does, but when reflecting it it prints some random characters. This is the pikachu.

`````
                                         so                       
                                        sNm                       
  .yhyo/-`                             yNNN                       
   `sNNNNh:-.`                        :sdNN                       
     .yNNh:::::-.                    -:::/s                       
       .sh::::::::-.                `:::::-                       
         `.:/::::::::.  `           -:::::.                       
            `.-:/:::::::::::::-.`   ::::::                        
                ``-:::::::::::::::-.::::/.                        
                 .:::::::::::::::::::::/:                         
                .::oh//:::::::::::::::::`                         
               .:::ymy+::::::::::::::::.                          
              .oo:::::::::/:::::o/yo::/                           
             `ooo/::::+osss+::::ommo::-                           
             `oo+:::::++///oyo:::::::/`                           
              -/::::::/:::::+/:::::/++.--::::.                    
            ``.:/:::::/::::/:::::/ooo+:::::::/`                   
         `-::::::::::::/:/:::::::+oo/:::::://:```                 
        `/::::::::::::/:::::::/::/::::::::/::::::::::--.`         
         ::::::::::::://:::::::::::::::::/:::::::::::::::::--.`   
         `:///:::::////::::::::::::::/:. :::/:::::::::::::::::::` 
           `-/////:::::::::::::::://:.  .:://///::::::::::::::.   
            :::::::::::::::::::::::`    :://///////::::::::-.     
           -::::::::::::::::::::::. ----:://:   `.--::/::-`       
          .:::::::::::::::::::::::` :/::::/-           ``         
         `::::::::::::::::::::::::. :+/--:.                       
         -::::::::::::::::::::::::+ossy                           
         /:::::::::::::::::::::::::/:/+                           
        `/::::::::::::::::::::::::::`                             
         .//////:::::://///:::::::::`                             
      `-//::////...````.---::////:/-.                             
      `.-...``                .-::/::/:.                          
                                   ``.-.
`````

it print this:

````
                   os
                   mNs
                   NNNy                             `-/oyhy.
                   NNds:                        `.-:hNNNNs`
                   s/:::-                    .-:::::hNNy.
                   -:::::`                .-::::::::hs.
                   .:::::-           `  .::::::::/:.`
                    ::::::   `.-:::::::::::::/:-.`
                    ./::::.-:::::::::::::::-``
                     :/:::::::::::::::::::::.
                     `::::::::::::::::://ho::.
                      .::::::::::::::::+ymy:::.
                       /::oy/o:::::/:::::::::oo.
                       -::ommo::::+ssso+::::/ooo`
                       `/:::::::oyo///++:::::+oo`
                .::::--.++/:::::/+:::::/::::::/-
               `/:::::::+ooo/:::::/::::/:::::/:.``
             ```://::::::/oo+:::::::/:/::::::::::::-`
     `.--::::::::::/::::::::/::/:::::::/::::::::::::/`
````

`.--:::::::::::::::::/::::::::::::::::://:::::::::::::`
:::::::::::::::::::/::: .:/::::::::::::::////:::::///:
   `.:::::::::::::://///::.  .://:::::::::::::::://///-`
     .-:::::::://///////::    `:::::::::::l▌`w£ⁿrtÉ               X║ `P`║`0                   ¡ⁿrt`╗       `É                           ::::`╗       `h╗`
         ````` -/::::/: `:::::::::::::::::::::::.
          |▌`wyæst               X╗` ╪╗`            Ü╪«$           ä╗` ╛·rt       @╗`    ╚╓` P╓vt╩Q│P■   É╓` 9▌⌠v   ╪╗`    ░╗`            ╟α⌠v::::                             $           ╫` ╫`
                   +/:/:::::::::::::::::::::::::/
                             `::::::::::::::::::::::::::/`
                             `::::::::://///:::::://////.
                             .-/:////::---.````...////:://-`
                          .:/::/::-. `````...-.`

what is causing this, I'm sure it is how im sending and saving the reversed char arrays. But I have no idea how to fix it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define S 100

char** Reverse(char str[S][S],int i);
void printImage(char str[S][S],int i);
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    FILE *fp;
    char buf[S],buf2[S][S],**refpic;
    fp = fopen("pikachu.txt","r");
    while(fgets(buf, 100, fp) != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(buf2[i],buf);
        i++;


    }
    fclose(fp);



    printImage(buf2,i);

    refpic=Reverse(buf2,i);
    strncpy(refpic,buf2,S);
    printImage(refpic,i);

    return 0;
}
char** Reverse(char str[S][S],int i)
{
    int a=0,b=0;
    char refpic[S][S];

    for(a=0;a<i;a++)
    {

        for(b=0;b<100;b++)
        {

            refpic[a][b]=str[a][99-b];
        }
    }

    return refpic;
}
 void printImage(char str[S][S],int i)
{
    int a=0,b=0;


    for(a=0;a<i;a++)
        {
            for(b=0;b<100;b++)
            {
                printf("%c", str[a][b]);
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem seems to be that your program allocates a maximum line width (100), read lines shorter than that (66), then tries to reverse the line read based on the maximum width, basically copying garbage.  You need to either work with the actual width, or pad to the maximum with with spaces, or both.

Another issue is that you use the same value `#define S 100` for both the maximum width and maximum height, which isn't realistic, and then don't use it consistently in your code:

```
char buf[S],buf2[S][S],**refpic;
while(fgets(buf, 100, fp) != NULL)
strncpy(refpic,buf2,S);
for(b=0;b<100;b++)
refpic[a][b]=str[a][99-b];
void printImage(char str[S][S],int i)
```

We shouldn't see any 100's (or 99's).

You also seem to assume the image will be space padded on the right which isn't always a given with ASCII art.  And it's not clear that you're dealing with the trailing newline correctly in the reversal. Below is my rework addressing the above issues and some style tweaks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINES 200
#define MAX_COLUMNS 100

void printImage(char image[][MAX_COLUMNS], int n_lines, int n_cols)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < n_lines; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < n_cols; b++)
        {
            putchar(image[a][b]);
        }

        putchar('\n');
    }
}

void reverseImage(char image[][MAX_COLUMNS], char reverse[][MAX_COLUMNS], int n_lines, int n_cols)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < n_lines; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < n_cols; b++)
        {
            reverse[a][b] = image[a][n_cols - b - 1];
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    char buf2[MAX_LINES][MAX_COLUMNS]; 

    int row = 0, columns = 0;

    while (fgets(buf2[row], MAX_COLUMNS, fp) != NULL)
    {
        size_t length = strlen(buf2[row]) - 1;

        if (length > columns)
        {
            columns = length;
        }

        for (int j = length; j < MAX_COLUMNS - 1; j++)
        {
            buf2[row][j] = ' ';
        }

        buf2[row][MAX_COLUMNS - 1] = '\0';

        row++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    printImage(buf2, row, columns);

    char refpic[MAX_LINES][MAX_COLUMNS];

    reverseImage(buf2, refpic, row, columns);

    printImage(refpic, row, columns);

    return 0;
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

`````
> ./a.out aardvark.txt
    ,__    _,            ___                   
     '.`\ /`|     _.-"```   `'.                
       ; |  /   .'             `}              
       _\|\/_.-'                 }             
   _.-"a                 {        }            
.-`  __    /._          {         }\           
'--"`  `""`   `\   ;    {         } \          
               |   } __ _\       }\  \         
               |  /;`   / :.   }`  \  \        
               | | | .-' /  / /     '. '._     
      jgs    .'__/-' ````.-'.'        '-._'-._ 
             ```        ````              `"""`
                   ___            ,_    __,    
                .'`   ```"-._     |`/ \`.'     
              }`             '.   /  | ;       
             }                 '-._/\|\_       
            }        {                 a"-._   
           \}         {          _./    __  `-.
          \ }         {    ;   \`   `""`  `"--'
         \  \}       \_ __ }   |               
        \  \  `}   .: /   `;/  |               
     _.' .'     / /  / '-. | | |               
 _.-'_.-'        '.'-.```` '-/__'.    sgj      
`"""`              ````        ```             
>
`````

Note that reversing ASCII art isn't always a good idea...